# How to change File path to PDF that is being displayed in address bar?

Tags: php, tcpdf

I have this PDF file that was made in PHP file..I only view the generated PDF, and not saving to my computer,. the location of the PHP file is
something like this for example.

```
localhost/this/is/my/very/long/file/path/tcpdf/myfile.php
```

When generating PDF, that very long url is the one displaying on the address bar. 
I want to display only the PDF file name to the address bar instead of that long url example

```
localhost/myPDF/myfile.php
```

Any Ideas?

Answer (score 1):

You could try using url rewriting to fix it, but you'd probably have to either route the downloads through a script, or find a way to make the rewrite be able to figure out which PDF to open from a given url.

Edit: Upon re-reading the question, you definitely want to use this method. Route the url to your php endpoint, using apache or nginx (depending on which you use to host the script) url rewriting capabilities.

Answer (score 0):

When you generate the PDF, copy it into a folder with the shorter path. That would probably the easiest solution.